# Conflicto con funciones javascript dentro de un HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo un problema con con JavaScript y CSS. Estoy intentando agregar dos funciones similares en las que al hacer click  se muestren ciertos elementos (un menú tipo hamburguesa y por otro lado, una imagen), y al dar click en un botón de cerrar, el efecto desaparece. Sin embargo, parece que hay conflictos entre las funciones ya que por separado trabajan a la perfección pero juntas, como las necesito, no lo hacen.

Estoy colocando las funciones directamente en el HTML, no sé si por ahí pueda estar el problema,  estos son mis códigos:

EL primero es un menú tipo hamburguesa que al dar click sobre la imagen se despliegan las diferentes secciones:

```html
<script>
        const mainMenu = document.querySelector('.mainMenu');
        const closeMenu = document.querySelector('.closeMenu');
        const openMenu = document.querySelector('.openMenu');

        openMenu.addEventListener('click',show);
        closeMenu.addEventListener('click',close);

        function show(){
        mainMenu.style.display = 'flex';
        mainMenu.style.top = '0';
        }
        function close(){
        mainMenu.style.top = '-100%';
        }
</script>
```

Y este es un texto al que dándole click se abre una imagen con un efecto `popup`:

```html
                <script>
                    const open = document.getElementById('open');
                    const modal_container =                   document.getElementById 'modal_container');
                    const close = document.getElementById('modal_container');

                    open.addEventListener ('click', () => {
                    modal_container.classList.add('show');
                    });

                    close.addEventListener ('click', () => {
                    modal_container.classList.remove('show');
                    });
                </script>
```

Quiero señalar que mis funciones están en archivos diferentes, con archivos CSS distintos pero todo dentro de un mismo proyecto. El menú de hamburguesa esta en un archivo `partial` que es mi header.ejs el cual se repite en todas las páginas del proyecto mientras que la imagen con efecto `Popup` solamente esta en un archivo (producto.ejs) y aún así afecta al resto. ¿Mi problema esta en en la lógica de java o en el CSS? Como lo mencioné anteriormente si borro o comento una de las funciones la otra trabaja bien pero intentando colocar ambas sólo funciona una . Espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes declaradas dos veces **close** una como constante y otra como función, de hecho te debe saltar un error en console advirtiéndolo.
Una solución es usar identificadores distintos para la constatne close y pra la función close().

Comment: Ay, tienes toda la razón, ¿Cómo no lo vi? Las nombré de manera diferente ¡y me funcionó a la perfección! Gracias por tu ayuda :)